# How to fill outside overlay circle in iOS 7 on map

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit, mkoverlay

I need the same filled space around circle on the map as in Reminders app in iOS7. I think need to use the method `applyFillPropertiesToContext:atZoomScale` or `fillPath:inContext:`.

[image: iOS 7 Reminders]

Comment: Post what you have tried and point out what issue you are having.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem:

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Fill full map rect with some color.
    CGRect rect = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.4f].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // Clip rounded hole.
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, [self rectForMapRect:[self.overlay boundingMapRect]]);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // Draw circle
    [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
}
```

Comment: I used the above code but in my case , the circle isn't drawn, only the black semi transparrent overlay is shown. Can you please help me to have same output as you