# iOS 10 MapKit previous layer zoom issue

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, ios10

I am working in a map application which renders a polyline over a map. I am having an issue when zooming, it keeps the previous polyline on the tile.

I have tried to force redrawing:

```
[self.mapView reloadInputViews];
[self.mapView.layer setNeedsDisplay];
[self.mapView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Also I tried to slow the zoom speed, but the issue is still in there:

```
[MKMapView animateWithDuration:2
                         delay:0
        usingSpringWithDamping:0.6
         initialSpringVelocity:10
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                    animations:^{
                        [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:unionRectThatFits
                                            edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 10, 20, 10)
                                               animated:YES];
                    }
                    completion: nil];
```

Does anyone know about this?

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the same issue! Only started in iOS10

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue and can't find a way to fix this.

Comment: Hi , How did you solve this issue .

Comment: Hey , you know how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

I found the resolution to the problem here: [How to refresh an MKOverlayRenderer when mapView change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544354/how-to-refresh-an-mkoverlayrenderer-when-mapview-change)

So I added:

```
override var boundingMapRect: MKMapRect {

    return MKMapRectWorld
}
```

To my MKPolyline & MKCircle subclass.

Comment: Hi PJeremyMalouf, I tried your solution. It didn't have any effect on the map rendering. If you have any other ideas, please get in touch.