# MKPolyline strange rendering related with zooming in MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

I have very simple View Controller to demonstrate this strange rendering behavior of MKPolyline. Nothing special just normal api calls.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        map.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let p1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51, longitude: 13)
        var coords = [
            p1,
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.1, longitude: 13),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.2, longitude: 13),
            CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.3, longitude: 13)
        ]

        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: coords.count)
        map.addOverlays([polyline], level: .aboveRoads)
        let cam = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: p1, fromDistance: 1000, pitch: 45, heading: 0)
        map.setCamera(cam, animated: true)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let r = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        r.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        return r
    }
}
```

The rendering of the polyline is very strange. During zooming and panning You can see some artifacts.

Take a look at pictures below:

Initial Screen
[image: Initial Screen]

After some panning
[image: After some panning]

After zooming out and zooming in again
[image: After zooming out and zooming in again]

How to fix this? I was trying to implement my own renderer but its the same situation. Like overaly is cached and it's not redrawing on time. I'm working on iOS 10, iPhone 6, Simulator from iOS SDK 10 xCode 8.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601768/mkpolylinerenderer-produces-jagged-unequal-paths

Comment: i had same problem and fixed it with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087736/ios-10-mapkit-previous-layer-zoom-issue

Comment: There is no proper solution for this issue and didn't find solution. anybody else ?

Comment: Because of this bug we choose to use Google Maps iOS SDK. It is much better in terms of Graphics, and coverage.

Comment: Hi Everybody .. What is solution of above problem in Latest IOS

Comment: is there any objective c solution version for this issue.

Comment: I'm surprised this is such a common issue with no concrete answer. I've been looking through SO but can't find anything.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 solution :

Create a subclass of MKPolylineRenderer

```
class CustomPolyline: MKPolylineRenderer {

    override func applyStrokeProperties(to context: CGContext, atZoomScale zoomScale: MKZoomScale) {
        super.applyStrokeProperties(to: context, atZoomScale: zoomScale)
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            ctx.setLineWidth(self.lineWidth)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your rendererFor MapKit delegate :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = CustomPolyline(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        renderer.lineWidth = 100
        return renderer
}
```

Your polylines won't re-render after zooming thus avoiding the artifacts

Comment: This actually works. But make sure that you set your renderer.lineWidth to a high value otherwise you won't see the polyline. I changed your custom class by setting ctx.setLineWidth(self.lineWidth * 100). This way you don't have to set a very high value in the delegate method.

Comment: As of this writing, iOS 11.3.1, this solution doesn't work. I got the polyline with a bad rendering as in the picture above. I'm looking for another solution

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciated