# How to prevent overlays on the map from disappearing when zoom scale changes in swift?

Tags: swift, mapkit, overlay, ios13, renderer

I am trying to render an overlay (polygon) on the map using swift MapKit. I can render successfully but when I zoom out too much then zoom in again, all the rendered polygons get disappear. How can I prevent that from happening and force the rendered polygons to stay on the map at all zoom scales? I am using MapKit and MKPolygonRenderer.

I add the polygons to the map using the following method in my viewController:

```
// function to add polygon overlay to the map
    private func addPolygonsToMap() {
        guard let polygons = arrayOfpolygons else {
            return
        }
        for polygon in polygons {
            mapView.addOverlay(polygon)
        }
    }
```

My view controller conforms to MKMapViewDelegate and here is the delegate method for it.

```
// method for overlay on map
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.fillColor = UIColor.purple.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        renderer.strokeColor = .black
        renderer.lineWidth = 2

        return renderer
    }
```

here is a simple demonstration with some points to draw a test polygon.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/polygonoverlay
I did not find any swift solution for this problem.

I am running on simulator with iOS 13.

Comment: you want an overlay not afected by the zoom of the map? is that what you are trying?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes, exactly

Comment: @Ali_C Hey, i had similar problem with MKPolyline. I posted solution in that question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631738/polylines-are-disappearing-when-zoom-closely/60453172#60453172